# Natural Deduction: Switching elements in premise to get conclusion

Tags: logic

How do I get from premise ~~(AvB) to ~~(BvA).
Been working on it for a long time but I haven't found the solution yet. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about natural deduction / logic / proof theory / mathematics instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `<->` denote equivalence. We have,

```
~~(A v B) <->  A v B         ; law of double negation
   A v B  <->  B v A         ; because v is commutative
   B v A  <->  ~~(B v A)     ; again, double negation
```

Thus

```
~~(A v B) <-> ~~(B v A)
```

Comment: OK @WillNess. In my answer I've used the mathematical meaning of the word, where a function `f` is *idempotent* when applying it twice does nothing, i.e., its composition with itself is the identity (`f(f(x)) = x`.)

Comment: @WillNess You are right. Thanks! I will fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks you everyone!

Comment: @GirriMuthhukumarPalaniyapan welcome to SO! you're supposed to accept the answer that helped you the most, by clicking on the big empty V sign's outline next to it.